# Problem with MacBook suddenly not reading WD hard drives

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk

I updated mac to Monterey and my two WD hard drives not working. It says Not mounted. Apple support can't help any more . It is not the ports or adapters as they are working with other storage system . They suggest going to a store as I don't want to lose the valuable data. Also try Western Digital  - not sure how to do that
Time machine is on one of them

Comment: Need some details to help here. How are you connecting? Via network, NAS, USB enclosure, etc.? How are the drives formatted? If in an enclosure, what type - WD Passport or a generic enclosure? What kind of drives are they - SSD, HDD, etc.?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WD passport. I'm not too technical. Connecting to MacBook via ports via adapter. As far as I know the hard drives are not corrupt - have tested them. The mac book just stopped reading them after updating. DOn't want to lose data